# SSIS development in SQL 2005 without BIDS

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

Is there any way to develop SSIS packages in SQL 2005 without using BIDS?

Comment: FYI, SSIS replaces DTS in SQL Server 2005. There is no DTS in SQL Server 2005, only SSIS.

Comment: @John Saunders - not strictly true - with the "Legacy Components" pack, SQL 2005 supports running and editing DTS packages.

Comment: @Pramodtech: is it DTS (legacy) or SSIS that you need to develop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to [create a package programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135946.aspx).

I'm not aware of any alternative graphical editors to BIDS.

To edit DTS packages, you need to install the [DTS designer components](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/4/D/44DBDE61-B385-4FC2-A67D-48053B8F9FAD/SQLServer2005_DTS.msi)

Answer (score 0):

You can also create and save very basic import/export packages from SSMS.  These can be loaded in BIDS for later modification.